# User input to specify array name [bash]

Tags: arrays, bash, shell, scripting, user-input

I just started learning bash/shell for fun, and I'm trying to create a simple script that should take user input, which should be the name of a pre-built array, and then `say` each item in that array with a pause in between.

Here's what I have so far:

```
#!/bin/sh
array=("foo" "bar" "baz")

read -p "Which array should I read to you? " answer

for item in ${answer[@]}
do
    say "$item [[slnc 1000]]"
done
```

Please let me know if you can point me in the right direction!

Comment: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/006

Comment: I tried it and it was working (mac env).
with pause inclided

Comment: Did you save it as a file? What extension did you use? How did you run it? Any details will be helpful. Also, what happens if you add spaces into any of the array values - does it still work then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access array using a variable array name like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

array=("foo" "bar" "baz")
read -p "Which array should I read to you? " answer

tmp="$answer"[@];

for item in "${!tmp}"; do
    echo "$item [[slnc 1000]]"
done
```

Then use above script as:

```
bash arr.sh
Which array should I read to you? array
foo [[slnc 1000]]
bar [[slnc 1000]]
baz [[slnc 1000]]
```

Comment: Thanks so much anubhava, I had a feeling there was a transitional step I was missing somewhere, and now I learned something new!